# Replace large img src with thumbnail img woocommerce products loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce, and by default it use the large image in the product loop.
The goal is that I want to replace each large product image **(1000x1000px)** with the thumbnail image **(300x300px)** which is contained in the same folder as the large image.

Here is the **html** code:

```
<div class="products_container">
 <ul>
  <li>
    <div>
       <a>
         <img class="attachment-entry wp-post-image" width="1000" height="1000" alt="IMG_2606" src="//wp-content/uploads/2015/08/IMG_2606.jpg" />
       </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div>
       <a>
         <img class="attachment-entry wp-post-image" width="1000" height="1000" alt="IMG_2607" src="//wp-content/uploads/2015/08/IMG_2607.jpg" />
       </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div>
       <a>
         <img class="attachment-entry wp-post-image" width="1000" height="1000" alt="IMG_2608" src="//wp-content/uploads/2015/08/IMG_2608.jpg" />
       </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
  ...
  ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

With a total of 24 products per page.

And the **jQuery** :

I tried to put the jQuery code under the `<script></script>` tag in the `child-theme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php` file before the `<ul>`, and in my **custom.js** file, both doesn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $('.products_container img.wp-post-image').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);

   $this.attr('src').replace('.jpg', '-300x300.jpg');
 });
});
```

If I put this code in the browser console, it replace the large image with the thumbnail as I want `$('.products_container').find('img.wp-post-image').attr('src').replace('.jpg', '-300x300.jpg');`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as the second parameter of [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

The function is called for each element in the set and should return the new value of the attribute you've defined with the first parameter

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.products_container img.wp-post-image')
        .attr('src', function(idx, src) {
            return src.replace('.jpg', '-300x300.jpg');
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your quick answer it work very well :)